# melt correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, duplicates, dplyr, correlation

I have created a correlation matrix in R using:

```
cor(df, use = "p")->df_corr
```

Then I melted the matrix using:

```
melt(df_corr) -> df_corr_melted
```

to get:

```
Var1 Var2 value
A    B    .1
A    C     .2
A    A     1
B    A     .1
B    C     .4
B    B     1
C    A     .2
C    B     .4
C    C     1
```

I'd like to remove the redudnant pairs. For example, I only need corr(A,C) not corr(C,A). I read through the filtering commands in dplyr, but since the row combination is actually unique, these aren't true duplicates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Subset (`filter` with `dplyr`) where  `Var1 <= Var2`. Use `<` instead of `<=` if you want to also omit the trivial X,X correlations.

Comment: @Gregor, great answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one go by using `replace` to set the diagonal and either the upper or lower triangle of the matrix to `NA`, and then just `melt(..., na.rm = TRUE)`:

Demo:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(replace(df_corr, lower.tri(df_corr, TRUE), NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#   Var1 Var2      value
# 4   aa   bb  0.5776151
# 7   aa   cc -0.4059593
# 8   bb   cc -0.5673487
```

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
df_corr <- cor(data.frame(aa = rnorm(10), bb = rnorm(10), cc = rnorm(10)), use = "p")
```

Answer (score 3):

Before melting you can do:

```
data.frame(Var1=t(combn(colnames(df_corr),2)),Var2=df_corr[lower.tri(df_corr)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `combn` and the `apply` function:

```
c_names <- combn(names(dat), 2)

cors <- apply(c_names, 2, FUN = function(x) cor(dat[x[1]], dat[x[2]]))

cbind.data.frame(t(c_names), cors)

   1  2       cors
1 aa bb  0.5776151
2 aa cc -0.4059593
3 bb cc -0.5673487
```

#### Data

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(aa = rnorm(10),
                  bb = rnorm(10),
                  cc = rnorm(10))
```